# Sharing docker containers sshfs mount with windows host via volum mount

Tags: docker, sshfs

I'm running docker on windows host. I have a centos container running with folder mount `-v c:/dockershared_folder:/mnt/shared`. Everything I create in my /mnt/shared will appear nicely in my windows host but when I mount sshfs to /mnt/shared/sshfs_folder it looks completely empty for host but work ok in the container.

So here's the question. Did I do something wrong or it shouldn't work anyway and I just don't understand the concept.

My intention is to make sshfs work in Windows since all those 3rd party sshfs tools for windows are bad, outdated or not working at all.